# import component in main.js in Vue project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Problem is by building my project in production mode.

I try to import component in my main.js with construction

```
const isBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined';
const VueHead  = isBrowser ? require('vue-head') : undefined;
```

In next line i use this component with

```
Vue.use(VueHead)
```

and become an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'install' of undefined.
```

I can't change construction with "require" on simple import. This option doesn't suit me (cause in this case i become an error with webpack `"ReferenceError: window is not defined"` and with construction with "require" i try to resolve this error).

full main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate'

const isBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined';
const VueHead  = isBrowser ? require('vue-head') : undefined;

Vue.use(VueHead)
Vue.use(VeeValidate)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

UPDATE: I try to start my application with pm2 in production mode. When i start with `npm run dev`, haven't problems or errors

Comment: can you try `import VueHead from 'vue-head';` then : `isBrowser ?: VueHead = undefined;` ?

Comment: Are you trying to build the bundle with `VueHead` only if is a browser?

Comment: @ElAlamiAnas doesn't work, cause '"VueHead" is read-only'; @D F i'm not sure. i tryed to resolve my problem with webpack and did find this possible solution